# delete only first hit /match with sed

Tags: linux, fedora, sed

```
$ echo -e "AsometAhingA\nsomethingA\nASomethiAng"
AsometAhingA
somethingA
ASomethiAng
$ echo -e "AsometAhingA\nsomethingA\nASomethiAng" | sed "s/A//"
sometAhingA
something
SomethiAng
$
```

I know that `sed "s/A//"` deletes the first match in every line.
But I want to delete only the first match in a text file or stream.
How can I do this?  
Like: `sed -i "MAGIC" file.txt`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, `MAGIC` is not a `sed` command, so you will have to use something else:

```
sed -i '0,/A/ s///' file.txt
```

```
perl -i -pe 'if (!$changed) {s/A// and $changed++;}' file.txt
```

```
echo -e "/A/ s///\nwq" | ed file.txt
```

Comment: In your `sed` solution, would it still work if "AsometAhingA" was the SECOND or later line, with "A" not happening anywhere prior?

Answer (score 7):

As long as it's GNU sed (which it probably is, since it's Fedora), you should be able to do:

```
sed '0,/RE/{//d;}' file.txt
```

Comment: Do you know if the semicolon is required? It seems to work without it for me, but I don't want to run into difficulties down the road.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a version of `sed` (non-GNU) that doesn't support 0 as a line address, then you can do this:

```
sed '/A/{s///;:a;n;ba}' file.txt
```

It prints each line as is until it finds one with the pattern. Then it deletes the pattern. After that it loops from `ba` (branch to "a") to `:a` (label "a") and reads and prints each line without looking for the pattern again.